# Why my text file is filling with values of data from database in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('mytest.txt', 'w');

$con =  mysqli_connect("some.host.com", "username", "password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_select_db($con, "database");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Apri_score");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $last = $num - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);
        if ($i != $last) {
            fwrite($fh, ",");
        }
    }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}

fclose($fh);
?>
```

The `mytest.txt` file is getting filled with commas but no data. I cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: You tried to echo your for loop instead of `fwrite` ?

Comment: According to php.net (the offiical PHP website) there is no function called `mysqli_num_fields`: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_num_fields&lang=en&scope=404quickref

Comment: you mean you mysqli_num_rows? that's available to get number of rows selected in your query.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen -- I can't understand your answer/question?
please elaborate. I have not used echo anywhere here. All I want is write to file

Comment: @unixmiah I want number of  fields as in my text file as I want to make sure the items in a row are separated my commas and once the row ends it again starts from next line

Comment: @Nikhil : Before you are writing the content to file, i just wanted  you to confirm whether you write something.. So i just wanted you to echo the content there i.e., `$fh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `mysqli_fetch_array()`, with a second parameter of `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.  This will assign `$row` with array keys containing the column names.  You are accessing them with numeric indexes from `$i` in your for loop.

Change it to either `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` or use `mysqli_fetch_array()` with the second parameter of `MYSQLI_NUM` which will return the array with numeric indexes.

Comment: Np, also should have mentioned, you don't need to write each column one by one, you can do something like: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        fwrite($fh, implode(",", $row) . "\n");
    }`